# How to show different labels while using nested_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

https://github.com/railscasts/196-nested-model-form-part-1/blob/master/surveysays/app/views/surveys/_question_fields.html.erb

In the above snippet, we show the same label (e.g. Question), but I need to show something like Question1, Question2, Question3 if I would like to create 3 different rows.

The logic to render the labels will be part of the Question itself, as part of the Question data model.
Also we would want to initialize few fields prior to rendering Question itself, how should I do that?

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base {
  content
  foo_id
  bar_id
}
```

In the above case, apart from content I would like to initialize foo_id, bar_id which will be different for the different questions

```
e..g Question1 ("Who is the president of US?", 1, 2)
e..g Question2 ("Who is the president of Spain?", 2, 4)
e..g Question3 ("Who is the president of Germany?", 3, 6)
```

Comment: what do you mean initialize? You can create questions with value foo_id, bar_id depend on you.

Comment: We would like to know how to provide different labels for each question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Embedded Ruby in the view to display the attribute of the Form Builder object you are working with. For example, in my HAML view, by calling `.object` on `contract`, I am able to access the attributes for that object.

```
= form_for @contract do [contract]
  %fieldset
    %legend="Enter Details for Contract #{contract.object.id}"
      = contract.label :name
```